# How to apply a qualified electronic seal to a PDF document using iText 7 and an external trust service provider?

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, itext7

I am currently in the process of a applying a qualified electronic seal to a pdf document, using IText7 library and an external signature service. But I have problems now when using the iText7 PDFSigner to actually sign the pdf, and are receving a 'Unknown PDF exception' by the PDFSigner.signDetached() method.
This is the first time I am using iText7 or actually working with digital signatures, so im not completely confident that I am doing it the correct way.

To apply the qualified seal to my pdf file, I have implemented the IExternalSignature interface, and in the sign method I call the external service with a web request to get the signature. The signature created by the external service is an **ECDSA** format signature. In the request I send the hashed pdf value, the hash signature and the hash signature mechanism used. The response I get is a signature which is converted to a byte array.

I am calling this external service from within the Sign method of my IExternalSignature implementation, the signature is returned, but I am having problems now when trying to run the PDFSigner.SignDetached() method, which throws 'Unknown PDF exception'

This is the code where I am trying to sign the pdf with the received signature

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePathLocal); //read the pdf file
            PdfSigner pdfsigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties());

           
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfsigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
            appearance
                .SetReason("reason test")
                .SetLocation("location test")
                .SetPageRect(rect)
                .SetPageNumber(1);
            pdfsigner.SetFieldName("sig");
            

            IExternalSignature serverSignature = new ServerSignature(certificateAuthLocal, AuthenticationCertificatePrivateKey);


            IX509Certificate[] certificateWrappers = new IX509Certificate[chain.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < certificateWrappers.Length; ++i)
            {
                certificateWrappers[i] = new X509CertificateBC(chain[i]);
            }

            pdfsigner.SignDetached(serverSignature, certificateWrappers, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Any help would be appreciated, since I have no experience using iText7 or applying digital signatures to PDF files. Not even sure if this is the correct approach.

The signing service which I am using is this one -> [aTrust](https://github.com/A-Trust/ASignSealQualified)

The code where I post the request and receive the signature back:

```
public Boolean PostRequest(string postUrl, string content, out string responseData)
    {
        responseData = null;

        byte[] rawContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

        try
        {
            
            Uri url = new Uri(postUrl);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentLength = rawContent.Length;
            webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(rawContent, 0, rawContent.Length);
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            if (WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError == wex.Status)
            {
                
                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData))
                {
                    //TODO: error text
                }
                
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The code you show looks fine. Thus, I'd assume there is an issue in `ServerSignature`. Can you share it? And also a PDF you signed with that code?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example PDF. The problem is that the signature bytes are too short: Your certificate has a RSA/2048 key. Thus, the signature bytes should be 256 bytes long. But the signature bytes in your example PDF are only 64 bytes long. Thus, either your signing server returns something incorrect in `SendRequest`, or your way of extracting the signature from the response there is incorrect, or the  content of the `signatureLocal` variable (or property?) you use in `Sign` is manipulated in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using a test certificate which was provided by the signing service. Above I have posted the method where I receive the response back and also the github link to the signing service. From their documentation, they are returning back an ECDSA signature format (which Im not actually familiar with at all, could that be an issue also ?) Could it be that the way I process the response back in my code causes this issue ?

Comment: I am also a bit confused with the Sign(byte[] message) method in the IExternalSignature, the parameter passed in is actually the content of the PDF file which should be signed? And this is already hashed based on the digest algorithm specified in the GetDigestAlgorithmName() ?

Comment: *"I am also a bit confused with the Sign(byte[] message) method in the IExternalSignature, the parameter passed in is actually the content of the PDF file which should be signed?"* - No. The parameter contains the (to be) signed attributes of the signature container that's going to be embedded in the PDF. One of these attributes contains the hash of the (to be) signed byte ranges of the PDF prepared for embedding the signature container.

Comment: *"From their documentation, they are returning back an ECDSA signature format"* - Your certificate has a RSA public key, not an ECDSA one. The 64 byte signature, on the other hand, could indeed be an ECDSA signature in plain format. Thus, there seems to be a mismatch between your certificate and the private key in the aTrust signing service.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I assumed there was an issue with the certificate, since currently I am using a test certificate, which is also provided by aTrust. We are currently in the process of obtaining a valid certificate from aTrust, which should contain the proper public key. But from your point of view, is the process of obtaining the signature from aTrust correct ? Or are there any other important steps to consider ?

Comment: *"But from your point of view, is the process of obtaining the signature from aTrust correct ?"* - Well, I have not yet dealt with their API, also I have not yet contacted web services in .NET yet (except using a wrapper that encapsulates all the stuff), so I don't know whether `PostRequest` and `SendRequest` do their job. One remark, though, putting the request result into a property may become a burden if you ever try multi-tasking that signing solution. One important thing, though: If the server indeed returns ECDSA signatures in plain format, you'll have to transform that into DER format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sign the PDF file with the returned signature, issue was that the certificate was not loaded. But when I open the file via acrobat reader and validate the signature, the signature is invalid, with errors about formatting or information contained in the signature

[image]

Link to signed PDF file: [signed pdf](https://file.io/6lxTHrMjEjlX)

The code in my IExternalSignature implementation:

In the Sign() method I hash the message with SHA256 :

```
public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        
        try
        {
            //hash the message digest
            var hashAlgo = new Sha256Digest();
            hashAlgo.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
            byte[] hashToSign = new byte[hashAlgo.GetDigestSize()];
            hashAlgo.DoFinal(hashToSign, 0);

            //return the signature
            signatureLocal = this.SendRequest(hashToSign);
            return signatureLocal;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then the call to the signature service is made:

```
private byte[] SendRequest(byte[] message)
    {
        var signatureRequest = new SignatureRequest();
        var baseUrl = "https://hs-abnahme.a-trust.at/SealQualified/v1";

        baseUrl = baseUrl.TrimEnd('/');
        
        var sid = "dummy";

        signatureRequest.AuthSerial = authenticationCertificate.SerialNumber.ToString(10);
        signatureRequest.Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(message);
        signatureRequest.HashSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(this.SignMessageDigest(message));
        signatureRequest.HashSignatureMechanism = HashSignatureMechanism;

        //request json body
        var reqStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(signatureRequest);

        string url = $"{baseUrl}/Sign/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sid)}";

        if (!this.PostRequest(url, reqStr, out string ResponseData))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var respObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SignatureResponse>(ResponseData);
        if (null != respObj)
        {
            return Convert.FromBase64String(respObj.Signature);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Additionally, the hash is signed:

```
 private byte[] SignMessageDigest(byte[] message)
    {
        //Generate the signature of the pdf hash data with the private key
        ISigner signer = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner(HashSignatureMechanism);
        signer.Init(true, privateKey);
        signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
        var hashSignature = signer.GenerateSignature();


        return hashSignature;
    }
```

The request is sent to the external service, which returns the signature back. This is applied to the PDF file, but when opening the PDF file, its invalid. What am I still missing here ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example PDF. But you should have edited all this into your question instead of posting it as an answer.